# troubleshooting jar loading conflicts in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros, sbt-plugin, scalikejdbc

I get the following error on sbt startup, when two specific sbt plugins are *added together* to a project in its build definition. One of these sbt plugins is [scalikejdbc](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc) and the other is [my own](https://github.com/CANVE/extractor/tree/master/sbt-plugin), and clearly their mutual inclusion in a project's build definition results in this error upon sbt startup:

```
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: package macros contains object
and package with same name: blackbox
```

Clearly, it looks as if each plugin brings along a different version of [scala.reflect.macros](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.10.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/macros) thus causing this error. I can poke inside the jars of the sbt plugins, and indeed one of them may seem to bring along a `scala/reflect/macros/blackbox.class` ―

```
$ jar -tvf scalikejdbc-core_2.10/jars/scalikejdbc-core_2.10-2.4.2.jar | grep black

  0 Sat Jun 11 15:51:10 IDT 2016 scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/    
405 Sat Jun 11 15:51:04 IDT 2016 scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/package$.class    
419 Sat Jun 11 15:51:04 IDT 2016 scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/package.class
```

― however it's hard to positively conclude what gets loaded by sbt during this early startup phase, in order to figure which versions of this package are involved here and which dependencies bring them along.

Thanks for your suggestions about how to proceed with this investigation!

---

And just for completeness sake ― I include below the full error given by sbt below only ― but I sincerely doubt it adds any information so you can likely ignore it.

```
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: package macros contains object and package with same name: blackbox
one of them needs to be removed from classpath
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders.enterPackage(SymbolLoaders.scala:66)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$4.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:244)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$4.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:243)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:194)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1231)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.scala$reflect$internal$pickling$UnPickler$Scan$$fromName$1(UnPickler.scala:207)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readExtSymbol$1(UnPickler.scala:226)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbol(UnPickler.scala:250)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolRef(UnPickler.scala:783)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:335)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:171)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readTypeRef(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:345)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:171)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readTypeRef(UnPickler.scala:792)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readAnnotationInfo(UnPickler.scala:466)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolAnnotation(UnPickler.scala:491)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.run(UnPickler.scala:88)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:908)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:1084)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:580)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:261)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:194)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1231)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:244)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:300)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:247)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:194)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.load(SymbolLoaders.scala:210)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.typeParams(Symbols.scala:1489)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.scala$reflect$internal$Types$$isRawIfWithoutArgs(Types.scala:4394)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$$anon$11.apply(Types.scala:4416)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TermSymbol.scala$reflect$internal$Symbols$TermSymbol$$cook$1(Symbols.scala:2581)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TermSymbol.doCookJavaRawInfo(Symbols.scala:2589)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.cookJavaRawInfo(Symbols.scala:1442)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.checkAccessible(Infer.scala:384)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$makeAccessible(Typers.scala:605)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIdent$2(Typers.scala:5201)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIdentOrWildcard$1(Typers.scala:5218)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5561)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5642)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5727)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5735)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.importSig(Namers.scala:1357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.getSig$1(Namers.scala:1460)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1463)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Namers.scala:728)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:727)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:727)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Namers$Namer$$logAndValidate(Namers.scala:1496)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:727)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:726)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.completeImpl(Namers.scala:1611)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter$class.complete(Namers.scala:1619)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.complete(Namers.scala:1609)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1231)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2912)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$61.apply(Typers.scala:3032)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$61.apply(Typers.scala:3032)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3032)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5301)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5642)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:99)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:464)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(Eval.scala:177)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:177)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:177)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.atPhase(SymbolTable.scala:207)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:177)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:182)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:152)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:122)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:271)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:109)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:725)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:731)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:730)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:730)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:738)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:738)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:738)
    at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:749)
    at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:555)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:584)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:452)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:456)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:344)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:299)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:295)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:286)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:492)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:492)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:54)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
error: error while loading package, class file '/home/user/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.11/sbt-0.13.11.jar(sbt/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/error reading Scala signature of package.class: package macros contains object and package with same name: blackbox
one of them needs to be removed from classpath)
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

Comment: When loading the project with either of the colliding plugins _alone_ (works without any error), then using [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to observe the dependencies, the project depends on `org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8` in both cases. So not much to look for there....

Comment: Did you try to compile your plugin to exactly the same scala version as  scalikejdbc? I know that when you compile a plugin you need to compile it over the Scala version of SBT. That is something around the 2.10.X range, not 2.11 for sure.

Comment: Yes, I did my best to confirm that through the build files, however is there a way to verify that through the jars themselves?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there is. If you did define this inside your build.sbt, then it should have compiled it to the proper scala version. Can you add an exclusion rule in your POM file? Something to say that a dependency is provided or just simple exclude it? Do you actually publish your plugin (local or to a maven repo)?

Comment: @marios To use my plugin, which is WIP, I `sbt publishLocal`. I guess a jar can't contain the Scala version it was built with as that's not facilitated by the jar file specification or something like that.

Comment: FWIW giving some advice to someone coming to this issue later on also having problems with plugin classpaths. Try adding `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-verbose", "-Ylog-classpath")` to `project/plugins.sbt`. This will print out detailed information when the scala compiler loads classes when compiling the build. This should give a hint from which the jar the conflicting classes came from.

Answer (score 2):

Copying @jrudolph's comment here:

> FWIW giving some advice to someone coming to this issue later on also having problems with plugin classpaths. Try adding `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-verbose", "-Ylog-classpath")` to `project/plugins.sbt`. This will print out detailed information when the scala compiler loads classes when compiling the build. This should give a hint from which the jar the conflicting classes came from.