# Maven build Issue with then namespace confict

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, scalatest

So, I am trying to build my project in maven and am getting this weird error during compile time. A duplicate of the question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046778/troubleshooting-jar-loading-conflicts-in-sbt) but the solution provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493328/compile-error-when-killing-topology-from-storm-bolt-programatically-object-and/51495053#51495053) didn't work for me. It is still complaining about the namespace conflict during compile time. Am not that much familiar with maven so any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: package macros contains object and package with same name: blackbox
one of them needs to be removed from classpath
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders.enterPackage(SymbolLoaders.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:270)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.scala$reflect$internal$pickling$UnPickler$Scan$$fromName$1(UnPickler.scala:217)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readExtSymbol$1(UnPickler.scala:258)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbol(UnPickler.scala:284)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolRef(UnPickler.scala:649)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readThisType$1(UnPickler.scala:398)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:413)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:179)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readTypeRef(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:417)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$$anonfun$readTypeRef$1.apply(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:179)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readTypeRef(UnPickler.scala:658)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readAnnotationInfo(UnPickler.scala:492)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolAnnotation(UnPickler.scala:515)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.run(UnPickler.scala:97)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:840)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:1017)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:502)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:139)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeqImpl(Types.scala:2227)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(Types.scala:2372)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:2240)
    at scala.reflect.internal.BaseTypeSeqs$class.compoundBaseTypeSeq(BaseTypeSeqs.scala:168)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.compoundBaseTypeSeq(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(Types.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:1356)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeqImpl(Types.scala:2227)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(Types.scala:2372)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:2240)
    at scala.reflect.internal.BaseTypeSeqs$class.compoundBaseTypeSeq(BaseTypeSeqs.scala:168)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.compoundBaseTypeSeq(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(Types.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:1356)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeqImpl(Types.scala:2227)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(Types.scala:2372)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:2240)
    at scala.reflect.internal.BaseTypeSeqs$class.compoundBaseTypeSeq(BaseTypeSeqs.scala:168)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.compoundBaseTypeSeq(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(Types.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:1356)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeqImpl(Types.scala:2227)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(Types.scala:2372)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfTypeRef(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:2240)
    at scala.reflect.internal.BaseTypeSeqs$class.compoundBaseTypeSeq(BaseTypeSeqs.scala:168)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.compoundBaseTypeSeq(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(Types.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseTypeSeqOfCompoundType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseTypeSeq(Types.scala:1356)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.baseTypeIndex(Types.scala:891)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseType(Types.scala:1401)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassTypeRef$class.baseType(Types.scala:1968)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef.baseType(Types.scala:2331)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.firstTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:405)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType2(TypeComparers.scala:552)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:320)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:779)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$validateParentClass$1(Typers.scala:1712)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.validateParentClasses(Typers.scala:1730)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1893)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1762)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5309)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5015)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5312)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5448)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:102)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:440)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:431)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:440)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:94)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:93)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1501)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1486)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1481)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1582)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:123)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:99)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:184)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:164)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:92)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    at scala_maven.ScalaTestCompileMojo.execute(ScalaTestCompileMojo.java:48)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] error while loading Assertions, class file '/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.11/2.2.4/scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar(org/scalatest/Assertions.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/error reading Scala signature of Assertions.class: package macros contains object and package with same name: blackbox
one of them needs to be removed from classpath)
```

And I updated the POM with following plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <scalaVersion>2.11</scalaVersion>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Yresolve-term-conflict:object</arg>
                                //this was added
                            </args>
                            <jvmArgs>
                                <jvmArg>-Xms2048m</jvmArg>
                                <jvmArg>-Xmx4096m</jvmArg>
                            </jvmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with your config and what you've tried so far, not just links to other questions.

Comment: The first link is essentially what I have tried (except I have tried it in maven instead of SBT) so far and stack trace is almost (if not exactly same). I have added the stack trace in the question. Also, I followed the POM update which is mentioned in the second link.

Comment: I didn't want to repeat what is already mentioned in the other questions hence the links